# Echo not displaying inside a div but worked outside of it

Tags: php, html, css, echo

I'm currently making a webpage and I have run in to some problems with echo being inside a div container.

My website is currently setup like this:
index.php has the header and a navigation pane on the left side. and there is a bodycontent div that will load in different pages depending on what is clicked.
I previously had the following code in my index.php right before my bodycontent div:

```
<?php   
//set the variables
$username   = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : '';
$email      = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '';
$password   = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : '';
$step       = isset($_POST['step']) ? $_POST['step'] : '1';

//validation        
if($step=='2'){
    if($username == '' || strlen($username)==0){
        echo 'username can not be blank<br/>';
    }
    if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false){     
        $errors[] = 'invalid email address<br/>';
    }    
    if($password == '' || strlen($password)<=4){
        $errors[] = 'password can not be blank or less than 4 characters<br/>';
    }
    $username=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($username));
    $email=mysql_real_escape_string(trim($email));
    $password=md5(mysql_real_escape_string(trim($password)));
    //mysql queries
    if(empty($errors)){
        //do something      
        $query = "
            INSERT INTO user
            (email, username, password, user_level)
            VALUES
            ('$email', '$username', '$password', '1')";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die ('error: '. mysql_error());
        echo 'new user registered!';
        $step='2';
    }
    else{       
        //error output
        foreach($errors as $errors)
        echo $errors;
        $step='1';
    }

}
if($step=='1'){
?>
```

I decided to move this piece of code in my registration.php page so the index.php looks cleaner for me.
However, ever since I moved the code from index.php to registration.php the echos are not displaying. If you need more code I will gladly post some more.. I don't want to overwhelm right now.

Comment: post full code for HTML divs and how you are accessing echoes

Comment: more code is nedded ,post the full code so that you can get answer you want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed in your final foreach loop:

`foreach($errors as $errors)` is missing an opening bracket;

```
foreach($errors as $error) {
 // instructions
}
```

Comment: That didn't work though. I think the issue is that when the user clicks the submit button inside the bodycontent div, the button's action is "index.php". My page automatically loads register.php when index.php.. so maybe the echos are getting wiped right after the submit button is pressed?

Comment: No, there are no missing brackets (although brackets could be added for readability, but indenting also could improve) The code could read `foreach($errors as $errors) { echo $errors; }`

Comment: Yup! The issue was the reloading of the page was wiping out the echo statements.

Solution:

since I'm not including the register.php file in my index.php, the $errors array isn't being passed.
So what I did was near the top of my index.php I put this:

    ob_start();

    include 'register.php';

    ob_clean();

which brings in the variables from register.php.

I then just accessed the array in the foreach loop and now the errors from register.php displays in echo on the index.php.